# Is a function discontinous at points not in its domain?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, continuity, epsilon-delta

Famously, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x} = 1.$ However, whether or not it is considered continuous at $x = 0$ seems unclear to me. Another post has pointed out that Rubin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* [writes](https://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Eagboola/teaching/2021/winter/122A/rudin.pdf)

> If $x$ is a point in the domain of definition of the function $f$ at which $f$ is not
> continuous, we say that $f$ is discontinuous at $x$, or that $f$ has a discontinuity at $x$.

It does not mention discontinuity at points not in the domain of $f$, implying $f:D \to \mathbb{R}$  is only locally discontinuous at point $a\leftarrow a\in D.$ [Wolfram Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RemovableDiscontinuity.html) supports that, saying

> ...The given definition of removable discontinuity fails to apply to functions $f$ for which $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=L$ and for which $f(x_0)$ fails to exist; in particular, the above definition allows one only to talk about a function being discontinuous at points for which it is defined.

Then, 1) Would $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ be considered *neither* continuous nor discontinuous at $x = 0$ since its domain is $\mathbb{R}~\backslash~\{0\}$?

Other definitions such as [here](https://math.stanford.edu/%7Ejmadnick/T19.pdf) say that

> A function $f (x)$ is continuous at $x = a$ if the following all hold: $f(a)$ exists and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists s.t. $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = f(a)$,

which classifies $x = 0$ for $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ as a removable discontinuity.
If we look to the rigorous $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity, it states that for $f$ to be continuous at $x = a$, $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta>0$ s.t. $|x-a|<\delta,~x\neq a \implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon.$ Since the definition includes $f(a)$, which is undefined, is that considered discontinuous?

Which definition is correct?

Comment: $x\mapsto\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ is indeed "*neither* continuous nor discontinuous at $x = 0$", for the reason you wrote. And your last definition (identical to the previous ones apart from an inelegant end of sentence) does *not* "classify $x = 0$ for $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ as a removable discontinuity".

Comment: This question has been asked many times on this site before. I think the right answer is: while authors are free to define continuity however they please, it makes a lot of sense to only speak of continuity and discontinuity at points where the function is defined (and most serious textbooks in analysis agree with this convention). Asking whether $x\mapsto \frac{\sin x}{x}$ is "continuous" or "discontinuous" at $0$ is akin to asking whether $\pi$ is even. It's not a meaningful question, in my view.

Comment: Continuity is a property of functions. If you change the domain or codomain you change the function. You should expect it to have different properties if you alter them.

Comment: I vote for the second definition you presented as the correct

Comment: To me it makes perfect sense to say the function is discontinuous at $x_0$ if the one-sided limit exists and doesn't equal $f(x_0)$